# Reading different file one after another using BufferedReader in Java

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, java-io

I am using BufferedReader to read file in java.

Following is the code snippet:

```
String line;
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
//Here I want to open file named "file2.txt".
```

As mentioned in the code snipped above, i want to now open a new file.

What is the best way to do so ?

Should i first close br using br.close, and then again initialise br or what ?

P.S.: I am new to Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a method will make your code modular and easy to use. This will lead to re-usability of code and ease of understanding. Here is the sample code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    readFile("C:\\sample.txt");
}

public static void readFile(String filename) {
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would make a method and call it twice

```
void readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
     try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
         ...
     }
}
```

note that `BufferedReader` instance `br` will be closed automatically and make sure that you are using JDK 7 for this

Answer (score 0):

File I/O operations internally use [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern. So, `.close()` on the outermost object should close all internal I/Os

Answer (score 0):

Yes, close it first, but use this pattern ...

```
BufferedReader br = null;
String line;
try {
  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
  }
}
finally {
    if (br != null) br.close();
}
//Here I want to open file named "file2.txt".
```

Or, the *try-with-resources* approach (semantically equivalent to the above) ...

```
String line;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt")) {
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
  }
}
//Here I want to open file named "file2.txt".
```